# WPF DependencyProperty.UnsetValue throws 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that throws `System.InvalidOperationException` when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys because of a `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`.
 Stack trace and debug output give no hint who is causing the exception. Here is the stack trace:

```
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.RequestFlags requests)     Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValueEntry(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.RequestFlags requests)          Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp)         Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FocusVisualStyle.get()       Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation.ShowFocusVisual(System.Windows.DependencyObject element)            Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs inputEventArgs)              Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventHandler postProcessInput, System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs)    Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()      Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs input)   Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport inputReport)     Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ReportInput(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.Windows.Input.InputMode mode, int timestamp, System.Windows.Input.RawKeyboardActions actions, int scanCode, bool isExtendedKey, bool isSystemKey, int virtualKey)   Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ProcessKeyAction(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, ref bool handled)               Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.CriticalTranslateAccelerator(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys modifiers)               Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(object param)                Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)            Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler)   Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)          Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.Delegate method, object arg) Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, ref bool handled)               Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg)    Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore)          Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window)                Unknown
>             ProInspectX14x64.exe!ProInspectX.App.Main() Line 48              C#
```

How can I understand which `FrameworkElement` is causing the exception?

Comment: by divide and conquer :-) (meaning commenting out xaml pieces untill the error is gone)

Comment: You could take a look in main to see what's on line 48. Probably not going to do you much good but.... Open app.xaml.cs. Use the navigation dropdown that has your methods in it to open "Main". This is the auto generated code your error is referring to. Take a look at line 48.  Good luck.